# GoDaddy SSL On Heroku doesn't work

Tags: ssl, heroku

I purchased my SSL certificate from GoDaddy.

I made the common name www.mywebsite.com. 
In my DNS settings I have the website forwarding from the naked domain to the www.mywebsite.com.

I removed any settings inside Heroku regarding the SSL certificate from the GUI.

Then I went through the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#overview).

To recap, I generated my server.key by first creating the crs files and sending those to GoDaddy.

I purchased the $20/mo endpoint.

GoDaddy gives me a downloadable ZIP for my certificates, one with one certificate, and one with 3 certificates inside of it.

I run the following command to install the bundled version first with the following failing message that follows:

```
heroku certs:add server.crt server.key --type endpoint

No certificate given is a domain name certificate.
```

The reason I even tried to use the bundle is that my SSL doesn't work in firefox, and intermediary cert is not being included. After looking around for an answer on this, I couldn't find one.

So to get my website back up and running in the short term, I decided to just do what I did before, and upload the single cert. That works, but not really.

Now I get this message when I run the cUrl test:

```
* error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

Also, my website is down. :(

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why downvote? I've seen other questions regarding setting up SSL on Heroku from Godaddy. I'm already frustrated that I can't fix this and now when I ask about it I am penalized for it? Give me a break dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in my case seems to be that purchasing an SSL cert is not necessary on Heroku. When you purchase a paid hosting package they provide SSL certificates by default without having to buy their SSL add-on endpoint.

There are likely other use-cases for using a paid SSL cert, but in my case I didn't have to do that.